# Viewport and renderview images vastly different to saved image

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I am working on a nebula image using volumetrics and evee. I am following a tutorial and everything works fine until I save the image sequence. The images are almost invisible compared to the viewport and even rendered view.

Here is the viewport image (rendered view):

[image: Render preview]

And here is the rendered result after pushing F12:

[image: render result]

If I save the rendered image as .png leaving all render settings at default, this is the result:

[image: Saved image]

The image is there, but it's incredibly faint. If I import the image sequence back into blender for video editing I can adjust the multiply slider under 'Color' and recover a bit of it's original strength, but it eventually blows out.

If it's unclear, my question is, how to get saved images at the same quality as the viewport/render view images.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't grace this process with being an actual "answer", it is a workaround that got the job done:

[image]

Having arrived at a working solution in the volumetrics section of the node system, and having it all appearing as I want it in the viewport and the F12, render view window, I inserted a multiply node between the volumetrics workings and the output node. In the image I used 100 as the multiplier but this was entirely arbitrary and arrived at on a trial and error basis by saving out the render and looking at the saved image file. As I say, not really elegant, but it worked.